# Checking for null in edit text with for loop

Tags: list, kotlin, for-loop

I want to check for empty values ​​in edit text using for loop, I don't want to repeat code while doing this. I tried this but got an error. Can you help me

```
binding.apply {

  val editTextList: ArrayList<EditText> = ArrayList()
  editTextList.add(binding.etRegistedFullname)
  editTextList.add(binding.etRegistedEmail)
  editTextList.add(binding.etRegistedAge)
  editTextList.add(binding.etRegistedPassword)
  editTextList.add(binding.etRegistedConfirmpassword)
  editTextList.add(binding.etRegistedPhone)

  //Bu for dögüsü sayaseinde 15 satır koddan kurtuldum
  for (item in editTextList) {
    // Toast.makeText(this@RegisterActivity,item.id.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    when {
      TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextList.get(item.id).text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }) -> {
        editTextList.get(item.id).error = "Cannot be blank"
        editTextList.get(item.id).requestFocus()
      }
      else -> {
        if (isValidPassword(etRegistedPassword.text.toString().trim())) {
          if (etRegistedPassword.text.toString().equals(etRegistedConfirmpassword.text.toString())) {
            val user = getPerson()
            authcreateUser(user)
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(
              this@RegisterActivity, 
              "password and confirm password must be the same",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
          }
        } else {
          etRegistedPassword.setError("At least one number, one lowercase letter, at least one uppercase letter, no spaces and a minimum of 8 characters")
          etRegistedPassword.requestFocus()
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're code is already wrapped in `binding.apply`, you don't have to keep typing `binding.`. And it's easier to create a list using `listOf` than what you're doing by creating an empty ArrayList and then filling it one by one.

This code of yours doesn't make sense:

```
editTextList.get(item.id)
```

`item` is already an EditText so you don't need to get it from the list again. `List.get` is going to look for the item at that index in the array, which has no relation at all to the view's ID.

```
binding.apply {

  val editTextList = listOf(
      etRegistedFullname,
      etRegistedEmail,
      etRegistedAge,
      etRegistedPassword,
      etRegistedConfirmpassword,
      etRegistedPhone
    )

  //Bu for dögüsü sayaseinde 15 satır koddan kurtuldum
  for (item in editTextList) {
    // Toast.makeText(this@RegisterActivity,item.id.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    when {
      TextUtils.isEmpty(item.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }) -> {
        item.error = "Cannot be blank"
        item.requestFocus()
      }
      else -> {
        if (isValidPassword(etRegistedPassword.text.toString().trim())) {
          if (etRegistedPassword.text.toString().equals(etRegistedConfirmpassword.text.toString())) {
            val user = getPerson()
            authcreateUser(user)
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(
              this@RegisterActivity, 
              "password and confirm password must be the same",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
          }
        } else {
          etRegistedPassword.setError("At least one number, one lowercase letter, at least one uppercase letter, no spaces and a minimum of 8 characters")
          etRegistedPassword.requestFocus()
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I didn't check the logic of your code besides that.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. But I discovered another problem, my error messages in else show as many for count

Comment: example: 
It says "password and confirm password must be the same" 6 times

Comment: You’re checking the password inside the loop. Move that part outside the loop.

Comment: thank you so much for writing good code. Good evening